# imageWithCGImage make app crashed

Tags: memory, crash, cgimage

My project is automatic reference counting, but when I use CGBitmapContextCreateImage and UIIMage's method imageWithCGImage, something happened. I wrote some testing code, when the code running, the memory increased until the app crashed.

**The device:**

[16G, iPad2, retina]

**The code:**

```
(UIImage*) createImageByImage:(UIImage*)img
{
    CGSize imgSize = img.size;

    imgSize.width *= [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
    imgSize.height *= [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, imgSize.width, imgSize.height, 8, imgSize.width * (CGColorSpaceGetNumberOfComponents(space) + 1), space, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(space);

    CGRect rect;
    rect.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    rect.size = imgSize;

    // here bypass some transformation to the CGContext

    CGContextDrawImage(ctx, rect, img.CGImage);

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
    CGContextRelease(ctx);

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:[UIScreen mainScreen].scale orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);

    return image;
}
```

**the caller:**

```
UIImage* baseImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"corkboard.jpg"]; // any big image,e.g. 1024*768
for (int i = 0; i < 100;  i++) {
    UIImage* tempImg = [self createImageByImage:baseImg];
    tempImg = nil;
}
baseImg = nil;
```

**Is there someone who can explain? Waiting for your help!!!**

**Another thing: in the code, if I only replace**

```
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage ....];
```

**with**

```
[UIImage imageWithCGImage:img.CGImage ....];
```

**the error disappeared! But then the function changed, not met the original demand!**

Comment: Did you try adding *baseImg = nil;* to your loop?

Comment: i tried, it didn't work!

Comment: baseImg = nil; should be inside the loop.

Comment: I changed the caller, the baseImg definition now outside the loop, so the baseImg = nil; cannot be inside the loop.